# Error in Load image in NSThread?

Tags: iphone

I have a url which contain image address, i want to load that image via NSThread but i am facing problem. I am doing thing like this.

```
imageView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 55, 57)];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
 - (void) showImage {  
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:temp.strUrl]; 
UIImage *chart = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];  
[url release];
imageView.image = chart;
[pool release]; 
}
```

Please help me on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here.

```
[url release];
```

you are not supposed to release the `url` object . as you haven't alocated it, may be that is what you are facing problem with.

Comment: Thanks ankit that is problem which you raised, can you please also tell me how to parse xml using nsthread i mean any tutorial link or any other help???

Comment: this is the best to get started... http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser

Comment: but i need parse xml in background like i am image load in background, i want to do this with NSThread.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do it , but I think the best approach is to use NSOperationQueue , you can learn more about it here.. http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/